# GCP VM can't start or move TERMINATED instance

Tags: cloud, google-cloud-platform

I'm running into a problem starting my Google Cloud VM instance. I wanted to restart the instance so I hit the `stop` button but this was just the beginning of a big problem.

`start` failed with an error that the zone did not have enough capacity. Message:

> The zone 'XXX' does not have enough resources available to fulfill the request.  Try a different zone, or try again later.

I tried and retried till I decided to move it to another zone and ran:

```
gcloud compute instances move VM_NAME --destination-zone NEW_ZONE
```

I then get the error:

> Instance cannot be moved while in state: TERMINATED

What am I supposed to do???

I'm assuming that this is a basic enough issue that there's a common way to solve for this.

Thanks

Comment: Im im the same sitiuation... did you found a solution?

Comment: not quite. i just retried after a few hours and it worked